# Only save populated spreadsheets with filled in cells as PDF

Tags: excel, pdf, save, vba

I'm currently trying to modify a Visual Basic macro to only save spreadsheets in a workbook that have had populated cells.

The current macro just saves the entire 16 sheet workbook as a PDF yet a maximum of 9 of these sheets are sometimes left uncompleted, yet are still saved.

I would like the macro to automatically check if these sheets have been populated, once the 'SAVE' button is clicked and then proceed to only save the filled out (complete) sheets as a PDF.

I would massively appricate any help!

The code below is how the macro currently works when just saving the entire workbook. (There is an IF statement check before it is saved to PDF.)

```
Sub SaveAsPDF()

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("COVERPage1PRINT")
        If (Len(.Range("C24")) = 0) Then
            MsgBox "Ensure Serial Number or Stamp number are filled."
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf (Len(.Range("H17")) = 0) Then
            MsgBox "Ensure Serial Number or Stamp Number are filled."
            Exit Sub

        Else
            ChDir _
            "P:\Cells\Spool & Sleeves Cell\Flow Plot Records\EFA\Saved EFA PDF Archive"
        fname = Sheets("COVERPage1PRINT").Range("H17")
        ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
            "P:\Cells\Spool & Sleeves Cell\Flow Plot Records\EFA\Saved EFA PDF Archive\" & fname, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
            :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job
(edited code)

```
Sub test1()

Dim wbBook As Workbook
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
Dim test() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim pdfpath As String
Dim sheets_to_be_checked() As Variant
Dim a As Boolean
pdfpath = ActiveWorkbook.Path 'YOU CAN ADD YOUR PDF SAVING LOCATION e.g. "C\Users\ABC\Desktop"

i = 0
sheets_to_be_checked = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet3")
Set wbBook = ActiveWorkbook

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("COVERPage1PRINT")
    If (Len(.Range("C24")) = 0) Then
        MsgBox "Ensure Serial Number & Tag Number or Stamp number are filled."
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf (Len(.Range("H16")) = 0) Then
        MsgBox "Ensure Serial Number & Tag Number or Stamp Number are filled."
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf (Len(.Range("H19")) = 0) Then
        MsgBox "Ensure Serial Number & Tag Number or Stamp Number are filled."
        Exit Sub
    Else:
        For Each wsSheet In wbBook.Worksheets
            With wsSheet
                If IsInArray(wsSheet.Name, sheets_to_be_checked) Then
                    wsSheet.Activate
                    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("D4:D9, E10:E15, F4:F9, G10:G15, H4:H9, I10:I15, J4:J9, K10:K15")) = 48 Then
                        ReDim Preserve test(i)
                        test(i) = wsSheet.Name
                        i = i + 1
                    End If
                Else:
                    ReDim Preserve test(i)
                    test(i) = wsSheet.Name
                    i = i + 1
                End If
            End With
        Next wsSheet
    End If
End With

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(test()).Select

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
     Type:=xlTypePDF, _
     Filename:=pdfpath & "\ouput.pdf", _
     Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
     IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
     IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
     OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub


Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```

The answer might change a little depending on your definition of populated sheets. You would have to alter the condition "If .UsedRange.Address <> "$A$1" Then "
One possible alternative to above is WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1:Z100")) <> 0

Please let me know if you need any assistance with the condition or the code.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried it but I can't seem to specify the cells within the sheets which are defined as being populated, I'm also assuming that's what you mean when you say 'depending on your definition of populated sheets'? Each of the 9 sheets are identical with a set layout, and cells: D4:9,E10:15,F4:9,G10:15,H4:9,I10:15,J4:9,K10:15 are the cells which need to be completed.

Comment: I think replacing the **.UsedRange.Address <> "$A$1"** by **WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("D4:D9, E10:E15, F4:F9, G10:G15, H4:H9, I10:I15, J4:J9, K10:K15")) = 48** should do the job...

Comment: Please let me know if were able to try this solution. If you have any questions, I would be happy to answer.

Comment: Hi thanks for thank addition sorting. However, how do I insert my initial IF statements and PDF saving locations?? Because they don't work an are just hilighted in yellow.

Comment: Also, it's working however, all the other sheets need to be in the PDF save, apart from the 9 sheets called (Final,Final2,Final3,Final4,Final5,Final6,Final7,Final8,Final8,Final9) depedning on whether they are complete. These are the 5th,6th,7th,8th,9th,10th,11th,12th,13th sheets. The 4 sheets before and the 3 sheets at the end have to be included, whether they are complete or not. At the moment the code is only saving the 1st sheet as a PDF. Cheers for the help so far

Comment: Revised the code to include the IF condition to check for sheet name in desired list. Also mentioned the place where you can specify the pdf save location. Hope this works. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, I can see how this scode should now work. However, due to my lack of VB coding knowledge I'm unsure to where to put the PDF file location / path in the code? Also it says the 'IsInArray' isn't defined and is higlighted, as well as the 'Sub test1()' being highlighted in yellow, how can I fix this? Also where can I put in my if statement checks, which I've shown at the start of my code in my initial question? Many thanks for your continious help!

Comment: My bad. I forgot to add the function "IsInArray" earlier. Added it now. The PDF location can be specified in the 10th line **"pdfpath = ActiveWorkbook.Path"**

Comment: Brilliant! Everything works many thanks!! Just one thing still, where do I insert my initial if statements to ensure a file name: ThisWorkbook.Sheets("COVERPage1PRINT")
   If (Len(.Range("C24")) = 0) Then
        MsgBox "Ensure Serial Number & Tag Number or Stamp number are filled."
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf (Len(.Range("H16")) = 0) Then
        MsgBox "Ensure Serial Number & Tag Number or Stamp Number are filled."
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf (Len(.Range("H19")) = 0) Then
        MsgBox "Ensure Serial Number & Tag Number or Stamp Number are filled."
            Exit Sub
        Else

Comment: Updated the code. Hope I understood your requirement correctly. If everything works perfectly please mark the answer as accepted. Cheers!

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much for your help! I've already given you marks, Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

This is going to depend somewhat on what exactly you mean by *'automatically check if these sheets have been populated'*. My crystal ball says that each worksheet has a header row and would be considered 'populated' if there was any data below the first row. In that case, you could cycle through all worksheets and construct an array of worksheet names to be selected. Once multiple worksheets are selected, the PDF creation would be on `ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat` not `ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat` and only those worksheets selected would be included in the PDF.

```
Dim w As Long, sWSs As String, vWSs As Variant
For w = 1 To Sheets.count
    With Sheets(w)
        If .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.count > 1 Then _
            sWSs = sWSs & .Name & Chr(215)
    End With
Next w
If CBool(Len(sWSs)) Then
    vWSs = Split(Left(sWSs, Len(sWSs) - 1), Chr(215))
    Sheets(vWSs).Select
    ChDir _
        "P:\Cells\Spool & Sleeves Cell\Flow Plot Records\EFA\Saved EFA PDF Archive"
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "P:\Cells\Spool & Sleeves Cell\Flow Plot Records\EFA\Saved EFA PDF Archive\" & fname, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
Else
    MsgBox "Nothing to publish to PDF."
End If
```

I've tested this with my own sample workbook then tried to incorporate your code sample specifics into my method. If it doesn't work the first time post back a comment and I may be able to offer assistance.