# Select all sheets and print into single pdf file

Tags: vba, excel

I want to print all sheets to a single pdf file. an each sheet would be on the beginning of new page.

I've tried with:

```
Private Sub CommandButton9_Click()

 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Select
 With Selection
 .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
 "E:\tempo.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
 IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End With

End Sub
```

I've got a message :"Method 'Select' of object 'Sheets' failed."

Thanks!

Comment: See [Only save populated spreadsheets with filled in cells as PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26234627/only-save-populated-spreadsheets-with-filled-in-cells-as-pdf/26235899#26235899) for a couple of methods.

Comment: So loop  through the sheets like:     for each ws in thisworkbook.sheets

Comment: by the way, most likely the `select` failed is because you have some sheets that are hidden and therefore cannot be selected

Comment: @Raugmor You were right! I absolutely forgot one sheet that I actually wanted to delete..it was a hidden sheet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `activesheet.export...`
Use `activeworkbook.export...`
Each sheet will display by how you have the print setup for each sheet set.

Or use Variables such as:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook, Fnm As String

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Fnm = "C:\Users\Dave\Downloads\TestMe.pdf"

    wb.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Fnm

End Sub
```

Comment: It's working! Just small question - in the PDF file, I have one blank page between 2 sheets. What do you think, do I need to set print area, or do you have a better idea? I want to make whole program as lighter as possible. Thanks!

Comment: I found an answer `Set wbBook = ActiveWorkbook

For Each wsSheet In wbBook.Worksheets
wsSheet.Activate
ActiveSheet.UsedRange
Next wsSheet
`