# Print all sheets through CutePDF Writer

Tags: vba, excel, pdf-generation

I was using .ExportAsFixedFormat from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32945802/select-all-sheets-and-print-into-single-pdf-file), but unfortunately, Printed PDF had some issues about formatting and some symbols.

I've tried CutePDF Writer and it is OK.

Now, I want to select all sheets and to print as a single file, as the same with .ExportAsFixedFormat function

Is there any shortcut to select all sheets and to print them through VBA to PDF?

I've tried to insert an array, which I populated with sheet names. But I have an error with type mismatch.

```
Private Sub CommandButton9_Click()

Dim SNarray, i
Dim Filename As String

Filename = "E:\TestMe1.pdf"


ReDim SNarray(1 To Sheets.Count)
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    SNarray(i) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).name
Debug.Print SNarray(i)
Next



Application.ActivePrinter = "CutePDF Writer on CPW2:"
Sheets(SNarray()).Select 'Here is the TYPE MISMATCH
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, ActivePrinter:="CutePDF Writer on CPW2:", PrintToFile:=True, Collate:=True, prtofilename:=Filename

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: You didn't type your array, try `Dim SNarray() as String`. BTW, nice to see that we can select the printer, I've never done that but that may come in handy! :)

Comment: @R3uK still the same :) Same error appears.

Comment: What error? and which line?

Comment: @R3uK the same line as before..The line with Sheets (SNarray()).Select

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

Remove the parentheses from your array in your select statement

```
Sheets(SNarray).Select
```

Make sure that all of your sheets are visible or you'll get `Select method of Sheets class failed` error. That's not what you're getting now, but if there is any chance a sheet may be hidden, you might want to code for it. Also, if someone adds a chart sheet or macro sheet and you would want to skip that, you might want to code for that.

```
Sub test()

    Dim SNarray() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lCnt As Long

    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Type = xlWorksheet And _
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Visible = xlSheetVisible Then

            lCnt = lCnt + 1
            ReDim Preserve SNarray(1 To lCnt)
            SNarray(lCnt) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
        End If
    Next i

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SNarray).Select

End Sub
```

Finally, when you use `Sheets` without specifying the workbook, you are actually using `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets` if you're in a standard module and `ThisWorkbook.Sheets` if you're in the ThisWorkbook module. As long as ThisWorkbook is active, you're fine. But if not, your `Sheets.Count` may return something different than `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name` expects. In general, always qualify your references.  A `With` block is good for that.

```
Sub test()

    Dim SNarray() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lCnt As Long

    With ThisWorkbook
        For i = 1 To .Sheets.Count
            If .Sheets(i).Type = xlWorksheet And _
                .Sheets(i).Visible = xlSheetVisible Then

                lCnt = lCnt + 1
                ReDim Preserve SNarray(1 To lCnt)
                SNarray(lCnt) = .Sheets(i).Name
            End If
        Next i

        .Sheets(SNarray).Select

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: the code works, but I have another problem, when I want to see my PDF file, it says that my PDF was corrupted, and unable to open it. I've tried Adobe Acrobat DC  as well as Chrome to view pdf.

Comment: You should create a new question for that.

Comment: Sure, just to add as a bottom line, when I put into a comment section `', PrintToFile:=True, prtofilename:=Filename `, then it prints OK. Thanks!